# Need to Draw ImageView on top of another ImageView without using FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout [Horizontal Orientation] in which I have several ImageView objects side by side. I need to be able to drag the ImageView objects side to side.

I can drag them, but I need to be able to draw them ontop of each other as I am dragging.

So, if I have

(imageA)(imageB) side by side, and I am dragging imageA in the direction of imageB, I need imageA to draw on top of imageB and viceversa.

So far, I can get the dragging done no problem [by extending ImageView, capturing onTouchEvent, overwriting the onDraw method, and translating the canvas] however, as soon as the ImageView is moved, it is clipped because of its bounds. I try setting new bounds for the drawable of the ImageView but that doesn't work either.

How do I draw one ImageView on top of another ImageView [without using FrameLayout] ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you achieve any solution? I'm facing the same issue.